# How to use itemize in Table environment

Tags: tables, lists, itemize

I want to create a table like the picture below, and i wish to itemize the lamba_1 > lamba_2 > 0 using 'item style', which is the cell of each categories. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: Here's a hint: Use a `p{<len>}`-style column, and then you can use `\begin{itemize}`...`\end{itemize}`.

Comment: Hi @Werner, u mean the \begin{tabular}[pos]{p{<len>}} smth like this?

Comment: Yes. The proposed solution uses [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) which calculates the width of the `X`-column itself, but is very similar to a `p{<len>}` (fixed-width, `p`aragraph) column.

Comment: Ypur diagram would be so much easier to understand with some small and simple drawings like these: http://twt.mpei.ac.ru/TTHB/New-Chem-Kin/ChemKin/3-19.PNG

Answer (score 89, accepted):

For simplicity, I don't think you need to `itemize` the list. The MWE below uses `\tabitem` to set a fake item, letting you create the table in the regular way (also making the code more readable):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Classification of the criticel point $(0,0)$ of $x' = Ax, |\mathbf{A}| \not= 0$.} \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
    Types & Type of Critical Point & Stability \\
    \midrule
    1.~Real unequal eigenvalues of same sign \\
    \tabitem $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2 > 0$ & Improper node/node & Unstable \\
    \tabitem $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < 0$ & Improper node/node & Asym.~stable \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
    2.~Real unequal eigenvalues of opposite sign \\
    \tabitem $\lambda_2 < 0 > \lambda_1$ & Saddle point & Unstable \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
    3.~Equal eigenvalues \\ Subtype 1: Two Independent vectors \\
    \tabitem $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 > 0$ & Proper node & Unstable \\
    \tabitem $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 < 0$ & Proper node & Asym.~stable \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) provides the supplemental `tabular` eye-candy.

Comment: +1: This looks great and is minimalistic at the same time. Good job!

Comment: But there's a problem which is the table will extend the margin of the paper if I type a longer word in the stability column, such as I change Asym.~stable to Asymptotically stable.

Comment: @AndrewOoi: That's because all the columns are set as `l`eft-aligned. If you have such long items, use [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) with its `X`-column in the one you want to break.

Comment: Could you suggest a solution for multiline lists? The auto-justification seems to cause problems with the intending here.

Comment: When I copy-paste this code as-is and try to compile I get various errors.

Comment: @crypdick: Double backslashes ``\\`` underwent an arbitrary removal for posts prior to 2015. We're in the process of converting that. See [Double backslashes disappear from code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/7168/5764)

Comment: "Undefined control sequence."

Answer (score 22):

When I had the same problem I solved it with `tabularx`. Here's the code for your example (I'm assuming the number in the 4th row should be 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth = 155mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\setlength\hsize{1.4\hsize}\setlength\linewidth{\hsize}}X|>{\setlength\hsize{.9\hsize}\setlength\linewidth{\hsize}}X|>{\setlength\hsize{.7\hsize}\setlength\linewidth{\hsize}}X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Classification of the criticel point $(0,0)$ of $x'=Ax,|\mathbf{A}|\not=0$.}\\
\hline
Types & Type of Critical Point & Stability \\
\hline
1. Real unequal eigenvalues of same sign
\begin{itemize}
\item $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2 > 0$
\item $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < 0$
\end{itemize} &
\vphantom{1. Real unequal eigenvalues of same sign}
\begin{itemize}
\item Improper Node/Node
\item Improper Node/Node
\end{itemize} &
\vphantom{1. Real unequal eigenvalues of same sign}
\begin{itemize}
\item Unstable
\item Asym. Stable
\end{itemize}\\
\hline
2. Real unequal eigenvalues of opposite sign
\begin{itemize}
\item $\lambda_2 < 0 >\lambda_1$
\end{itemize} &
\vphantom{2. Real unequal eigenvalues of opposite sign}
\begin{itemize}
\item Saddle Point
\end{itemize} &
\vphantom{2. Real unequal eigenvalues of opposite sign}
\begin{itemize}
\item Unstable
\end{itemize}\\
\hline
3. Equal eigenvalues \newline Subtype 1: Two Independent vectors
\begin{itemize}
\item $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 > 0$
\item $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 < 0$
\end{itemize} &
\vphantom{3. Equal eigenvalues} \vphantom{ Subtype 1: Two Independent vectors}
\begin{itemize}
\item Proper Node
\item Proper Node
\end{itemize} &
\vphantom{3. Equal eigenvalues} \vphantom{ Subtype 1: Two Independent vectors}
\begin{itemize}
\item Unstable
\item Asym. Stable
\end{itemize}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table]

If you don't like the item symbols in the 2nd and 3rd columns, use `\item[]`.

Comment: two points: (1) the baselines of the items in the first column aren't even with (they're higher than) those in the other two columns; (2) the indentation caused by the `itemize` in the last two columns causes the text to be shifted unpleasantly far right.

Comment: This code doesn't work as-is for me

Comment: "criticel" should be "critical" (but don't worry; its not critical).

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay, why do you have to be so cretical?? 

Comment: Trying to put an `itemize` in an X cell of `tabularx` results for me in 4 equal errors: `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{tabularx}`.

Answer (score 10):

Using itemization with `minipage` might be an option if the newline (backslash) is overlapping to another cell. For example:

```
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Classification 1}} \\ [2pt]  \hline
      \textit{Classification 1} & 
      \begin{minipage} [t] {0.4\textwidth} 
      \begin{itemize}
      \item item 1
        \subitem subitem 2
        \subitem subitem 3
     \end{itemize} 
    \end{minipage} \\ [2pt]  \hline
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: +1. I actually wanted a bulleted list in a table, and this is the best solution for me. Even better that the `minipage` environment is the `varwidth` environment, which takes maximum width as an argument, and adjusts to its content.

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{50mm}|X}
   1. item 1 \par %
   2. item 2     & this works \\\hline
   1. item 3 \par
   2. item 4 \par
   3. item 5 & second line too
\end{tabularx}
```

A simple solution is using a `p` paragraph column, you can combine with `\par` to separate paragraphs within a cell. I used text labels here for each paragraph, but you could use bullets or some other style.