# List inside a table

Tags: tables, lists

I am trying to make two dofferent lists in two coulmns of table, but I am getting an error:

> something wrong perhaps missing \item

```
here is my code   \begin{tabular}{cc}

      \begin{mylist}
        \item text
        \item text
        \item text
        \item text
        \item text
       \end{mylist} &

           \begin{mylist}
               \item text
               \item text
               \item text
               \item text
           \end{mylist}

   \end{tabular}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `c` is like `\mbox` you need a cell for vertical material so not `cc` but `p{3cm}p{3cm}`

Comment: The use of & could be the problem. Did you tried to ecaped it: \& ?

Comment: You can use this topic [How to use itemize in table environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150492/how-to-use-itemize-in-table-environment)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not on this example but I've some problem with special character and & is in this case. The solution for me was to write \&

Comment: @RomainPicot the OP doesn't want to typeset a `&` the `&` is separating table cells.

Comment: @RomainPicot: `\&` just prints the `&` character, so it is no wonder, that your problem vanished after that, but it is not of use if you want to have the column separator in a table

Comment: yes. My bad i've missread. Sorry

Comment: @DavidCarlisle p{3cm}p{3cm} This solution worked, thankyou so much.