# How to achieve multicolumn item lists with independent content?

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize, minipage

I need three item lists next to each other, with a centered heading for each list.
Using the `multicol`-package [doesn't seem to fit my needs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398127/breaking-a-list-into-multiple-columns-in-latex) as **it doesn't allow me to fill my columns independently, does it?**

[Putting everything into a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150492/how-to-use-itemize-in-table-environment), does not seem to be appropriate neither.

I came up with a solution using `minipage`, though it feels like overkill, it's quite close to what I want. But I can't manage to arrange the minipages side by side with some spacing between the columns. How to get the three minipages to use 100% of the space, let's say:

**30% column one, 5% space, 30% column two, 5% space, 30% column three**

I tried it with `\hspace` but it didn't worked out.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
{\centering \subsection*{Header 1}}
\begin{itemize}[align=left,leftmargin=*,labelsep=1ex]
\item one one one one one one
\item two
\item three
\item four
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
{\centering \subsection*{Header 2}}
\begin{itemize}[align=left,leftmargin=*,labelsep=1ex]
\item one one one one one one
\item two.one \\ two.two
\item three
\item four
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
{\centering \subsection*{Header 3}}
\begin{itemize}[align=left,leftmargin=*,labelsep=1ex]
\item one one one one one one
\item two
\item three
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there anything much easier to achieve what I want?

Comment: Please see revision.  David pointed out that I had two extra spaces, which needed to be removed with the addition of several strategically placed percent symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed not only the intercolumn space added, but also a `\noindent` before the first minipage.  Elsewise, you exceeded the column width.  Indeed, minipages are a good way to handle this sort of multicolumn problem.

REVISED to remove 2 stray spaces that David pointed out, by inserting line-end percent signs.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
{\centering \subsection*{Header 1}}
\begin{itemize}[align=left,leftmargin=*,labelsep=1ex]
\item one one one one one one
\item two
\item three
\item four
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\kern.05\textwidth%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
{\centering \subsection*{Header 2}}
\begin{itemize}[align=left,leftmargin=*,labelsep=1ex]
\item one one one one one one
\item two.one \\ two.two
\item three
\item four
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\kern.05\textwidth%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
{\centering \subsection*{Header 3}}
\begin{itemize}[align=left,leftmargin=*,labelsep=1ex]
\item one one one one one one
\item two
\item three
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `Overfull \hbox (4.87216pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--34`  (.3+.3+.3+.05+.05)\textwidth+2 word spaces is two word spaces too much:-) `\end{minipage}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Ooops.  Fixed.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Good to know! I finally got what purpose actually have the often seen `%` at the end of various commands.

Comment: @thewaywewalk  Indeed, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines

Answer (score 2):

Just in order to show a table solution:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newcommand*\myTableHeader[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\large\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}@{}}
    \myTableHeader{Header 1} & \myTableHeader{Header 2} & \myTableHeader{Header 3} \\\addlinespace
    \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
        \item one one one one one one
        \item two
        \item three
        \item four
    \end{itemize*}
    &
    \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
        \item one one one one one one
        \item two.one \newline two.two
        \item three
        \item four
    \end{itemize*}
    &
    \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
        \item one one one one one one
        \item two
        \item three
    \end{itemize*}\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update**:

You can still use your old `itemize` definitions here. But for this, you have to manipulate the height of the white space in front of the second row. The image shows the result without correction. The code already contains a `\vspace{-10pt}` which would look quite well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand*\myTableHeader[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\large\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}@{}}
    \myTableHeader{Header 1} & \myTableHeader{Header 2} & \myTableHeader{Header 3} \vspace{-10pt}\\
    \begin{itemize}[align=left, leftmargin=*,labelsep=1ex]
        \item one one one one one one
        \item two
        \item three
        \item four
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}[align=left, leftmargin=*,labelsep=1ex]
        \item one one one one one one
        \item two.one \newline two.two
        \item three
        \item four
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}[align=left, leftmargin=*,labelsep=1ex]
        \item one one one one one one
        \item two
        \item three
    \end{itemize}\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \\ does not work for a new line within an item, `\newline` does not really what it should in this case and even if there is no forced linebreak, it's not aligned. Do you see a solution for that?

Comment: @thewaywewalk Yes, \\ will not work, as this is something else in a table. But `\newline` should be easy to read as well. Please see my update!