# ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. [when put item]

Tags: tables, itemize

By trying to compile the code below the following error will be raised for each \item entry.

**LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\Large{Awards and}  & \textbf{Department}           \\
\Large{Fellowships} & Course Name, 2014--2015       \\
            &                   \\
            & \textbf{Fulbright Scholarship}    \\
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\end{itemize}
            & City, Country, 2006-2009      \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full code? `&` is used in tabular/array environments or amsmath align, split,cases &c. environments.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. See also here: [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1):

`itemize` does only work in p-columns in tables. This should work

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{8cm}l}
\Large{Awards and}  & \textbf{Department}           \\
\Large{Fellowships} & Course Name, 2014--2015       \\
            &                   \\
            & \textbf{Fulbright Scholarship}    \\
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\end{itemize}
            & City, Country, 2006-2009      \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can use fake bullet points instead of `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}`, as was suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150492/how-to-use-itemize-in-table-environment).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\Large{Awards and}  & \textbf{Department}           \\
\Large{Fellowships} & Course Name, 2014--2015       \\
            &                   \\
            & \textbf{Fulbright Scholarship}    \\
\tabitem 1      & City, Country, 2006-2009      \\
\tabitem 2      &                   \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to note, that `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}` can be used inside a `\parbox{}{}` in a `tabular`-environment (which is similar to the p-columns).

Comment: @Skillmon Right. I think, `minipage` should work as well. The OP was giving so little information about requirements that I went for the easy solutions, leaving out the more fancy stuff :)

Comment: That is correct. I just think, that this (`parbox` or `minipage`) would be the least intrusive way because it doesn't change the other cells of the table.