# Pifont ,enumitem and table do not go together well

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, itemize, pifont

I would like to center "The Essential Points" by using `tabular`, `itemize` and pifont but it seems they do not go together well.

[image]

I tired [How to use itemize in Table environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150492/how-to-use-itemize-in-table-environment) but with no luck

Could someone help me with that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\large
\begin{tabular}{c} 
\begin{itemize}[font=\color{magenta} \Large, label=\ding{43}]
\item Prioritzing 
\item Planning
\item Organization
\item Self-Discipline
\end{itemize}
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the `itemize` into some sort of box. The `varwidth` package lets you create minipage-like boxes as wide as needed, up to a specified maximum width.

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\large
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
first &
\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}[font=\color{magenta} \Large, label=\ding{43}]
\item Prioritzing 
\item Planning
\item Organization
\item Self-Discipline
\end{itemize}
\end{varwidth}
& last \\
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I would show an image, but there seems to be a problem today with uploading them. 
[image]

Comment: @Educ - what is the point of using a one-column tabular? Confuzed.

Comment: i fixed it good job

Answer (score 4):

I propose a new column type, `I`, which is a `p{some length}` column, entering and leaving an `itemize` environment with convenient parameters, so that you only have to type the items in each cell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, bigstrut}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
    \makeatother
\newcolumntype{I}[1]{>{\compress\itemize[font=\color{magenta} \Large, label=\ding{43}, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, after =\vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip +\partopsep}]}p{#1}<{\enditemize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|I{3cm}|}%
\item Prioritizing\bigstrut[t]
\item Planning
\item Organization
\item Self-Discipline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a `tabular`, rather than `itemize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{essentialpoints}[1][c]
 {%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{%
    @{\enspace\textcolor{magenta}{\ding{43}}\enspace}
    l
  }%
 }
 {\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

X
\begin{essentialpoints}
Prioritizing \\
Planning \\
Organization \\
Self-Discipline \\
\end{essentialpoints}
\begin{essentialpoints}[t]
Prioritizing \\
Planning \\
Organization \\
Self-Discipline \\
\end{essentialpoints}
\begin{essentialpoints}[b]
Prioritizing \\
Planning \\
Organization \\
Self-Discipline \\
\end{essentialpoints}
Y

\end{document}
```

[image]