# How to create table with merged rows and bullet points within a particular cell?

Tags: tables, wrap, bullets

I want to create a table like this in Latex :
[image: Sample table]

I am unable to figure out how to go about merging cells in column 1 & 2 and also adding bullet points in column 3. Can anyone help in figuring out how to go about it ?

So far I am able to come up with this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150650/85834
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{2.5cm}{Deep Learning} & \ \makecell{Medical Image \\ Analysis} &
    \tabitem Built a deep learning model using Mask R-CNN for instance segmentation of nuclei images\\\cline{2-3}
                                           & \ \makecell{Image \\ Classification}\\\hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Time Series}       & \ \makecell{Walmart Sales \\
        Forecasting}                       & \ \tabitem Built a deep learning model using Mask R-CNN
        for instance segmentation of nuclei images \\
                                           & \ \makecell{Rossmann Sales \\ Forecasting}\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:multicol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was harder than I thought! I would think in LaTeX that this should be easy, but it's not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `enumitem` package you can define your own `itemize` like enviroment that you can use for lists inside table cells. `tabularx` additionally helps automatically make the table span the textwidth:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{nosep,
                  topsep= 0pt,
                  partopsep=0pt,
                  leftmargin= *,
                  label=\textbullet,
                  before=\vspace{0.3\baselineskip},
                  after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                  }
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| M{1.5cm} | M{2.25cm} | X |}
  \hline
  \multirow{3}{1.5cm}{\centering Deep Learning} 
  & Medical Image Analysis 
  & \begin{tabitemize} 
       \item Built a deep learning model using Mask R-CNN for instance segmentation of nuclei images 
       \item another long line of text
    \end{tabitemize}\\ 
  \cline{2-3}
  & Image \newline Classification 
  & \begin{tabitemize} 
       \item first long line of text 
       \item another long line of text 
    \end{tabitemize}\\ 
  \hline
  \multirow{3}{1.5cm}{\centering Time Series} 
  & Walmart Sales Forecasting 
  & \begin{tabitemize} 
       \item long text 
    \end{tabitemize} \\ 
  \cline{2-3}
  & Rossman Sales Forecast 
  & \begin{tabitemize} 
       \item long text 
    \end{tabitemize} \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Personally, I would recommend a different design:

[image]

Here, I have removed all vertical lines and replaced the horizontal rules by rules from the `booktabs` package. Additionally, I have aligned all entries of the table cells to the top and added some vertical white space to guide the eye.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{nosep,
                  topsep= 0pt,
                  partopsep=0pt,
                  leftmargin= *,
                  label=\textbullet,
                  before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                  after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                  }
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ p{1.5cm}  p{2.25cm}  X }
  \toprule
  Deep \newline Learning 
  & Medical Image Analysis 
  & \begin{tabitemize} 
       \item Built a deep learning model using Mask R-CNN for instance segmentation of nuclei images 
       \item another long line of text
    \end{tabitemize}\\ 
     \addlinespace[2ex]
  & Image \newline Classification 
  & \begin{tabitemize} 
       \item first long line of text 
       \item another long line of text 
    \end{tabitemize}\\ 
  \midrule
  Time \newline Series
  & Walmart Sales Forecasting 
  & \begin{tabitemize} 
       \item long text 
    \end{tabitemize} \\ 
     \addlinespace[2ex]
  & Rossman Sales Forecast 
  & \begin{tabitemize} 
       \item long text 
    \end{tabitemize} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```