# How do i create table with bullets in 2 columns

Tags: tables, bullets

How do i create table shown in image in latex [image]

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style
\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % 
Document margins
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ c | l  } 
\multirow{2}{2.6cm}{Achievements} & \tabitem reviwed 20+ publication  \\
& \tabitem Performed comparative analysis of MATLAB results with FEA results 
from material strength aspect \\
\hline
Impact & \tabitem Generated 2 Gear Design models based on feasibility 
analysis of geometric parameters of spur gear  \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What did you try? Please provide a minimal example code.

Comment: You can add your work so far. And you can tell me where did you get stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use itemize in Table environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150492/how-to-use-itemize-in-table-environment)

Comment: i have added code that i have used. Problem i am facing is text in column 2 is going out of document margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using the [`multirow`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow) package. The table can be scaled to fit the text width (first example) or manual line breaks can be used (second example):

```
\documentclass{article}
% Allows using the \multirow command, that allows table cells to span multiple rows (first parameter)
\usepackage{multirow}
% Provides \resizebox command that allows scaling an entire table
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Define line spacing in table
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
% Command for printing a bullet point with some spacing afterwards
\newcommand{\bulletpoint}{\textbullet\hspace{\labelsep}}

\begin{document}

% Table that is scaled to table text width
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{c|l}
       \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Work}}   & \bulletpoint Reviewed \textbf{20$+$ research} publications \& developed thorough understanding of Gear Design techniques \\
                                        & \bulletpoint Performed comparative analysis \ldots \\
       \hline
       \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Impact}} & \bulletpoint Generated 2 Gear Design models \ldots \\
                                        & \bulletpoint Graphically demonstrated \ldots \\
    \end{tabular}
}

\bigskip

% Table with manual line breaks (as separate table lines) and spacing for indentation
\begin{tabular}{c|l}
   \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Work}}   & \bulletpoint Reviewed \textbf{20$+$ research} publications \& developed thorough \\
                                    & \quad understanding of Gear Design techniques \\
                                    & \bulletpoint Performed comparative analysis \ldots \\
   \hline
   \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Impact}} & \bulletpoint Generated 2 Gear Design models \ldots \\
                                    & \bulletpoint Graphically demonstrated \ldots \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered LaTeX]

Comment: @yatharthmeena Glad I could help. Would you mind accepting the answer, so that your question is closed?