# How to correctly format a table with itemize

Tags: tables, itemize

I have this LaTeX code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
        \centering
        \caption{Classifiaction}
        \label{table:cc}
        \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabular}{|c||*{1}{c|}|p{0.4\textwidth}|*{2}{c|}}\hline
                \backslashbox{Classification}{Model}
                & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 & Model 4\\\hline\hline
                Class & Class 1 & \begin{itemize}
                    \item Class 1 if $A=B$
                    \item Class 2 otherwise
                \end{itemize} & Class 2 & Class 2\\\hline
                Method & Method 1 & Method 2 & Method 1 & Method 2\\\hline
                Time & Constant & Linear & Polylogarithmic & Exponential \\\hline
            \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which produces a table that contains a cell with itemized bullets. The table looks ugly as the text is not centred inside the cell, there are some useless space for example in the cell with items, the lines are not equally spaced, etc.

How can I improve this table?

[image]

I have tried to use this method of adding itemized bullets [How to use itemize in Table environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150492/how-to-use-itemize-in-table-environment) but I did not succeed, i.e., when I use `\tabitem ....\\ \tabitem ...` the new item is not in the same cell but in a new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i would redesign your table in the following form:

[image]

(red lines indicate text area borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \caption{Classifiaction}
    \label{table:cc}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{2}{l} p{0.28\textwidth} *{2}{l} }
    \toprule
\multirow{2.2}{*}{Classification}
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Model}                 \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
        & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 & Model 4     \\
        \midrule
Class   & Class 1 & \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=*,
                                    before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                                    after =\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                                    ]
                    \item Class 1 if $A=B$
                    \item Class 2 otherwise
                    \end{itemize}
                            & Class 2 & Class 2     \\  \midrule
Method & Method 1 & Method 2 & Method 1 & Method 2  \\  \midrule
Time   & Constant & Linear   & Polylogarithmic & Exponential    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

as you see, `\diagbox` is replaced with new row for "Model", "Classification" is placed into `multirow` cell.

for table is used environment `tabular*`, its width is equal to text width, for the list is used `enumitem` package. vertical lines are removed, for horizontal ones are used rules from the package `booktabs`.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use `\resizebox` with tables – it leads to inconsistent font sizes. I propose a solution with the `\small` fontsize, a reduced `\tabcolsep`, a more decent text width with the `geometry` package and `tabularx` to make the table fit  between margins. I reduced the first column width , playing with the `height` and `width` parameeters of `\diagbox`. For the liqst problem, I think it will look nicer  left aligned at the left border of the cell, and without verical spacing. Last, I replaced `\hline` with `\ hhline` to have nicer intersections between vertical and horizontal rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx} 
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{array, caption, tabularx, hhline}
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering\small
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \caption{Classification}
     \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
    \label{table:cc}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c||*{1}{c|}| >{\compress}X|*{2}{c|}}
        \hhline{-||-||---}
            \diagbox[height=7ex, width=9em]{Classification}{\raisebox{-1.6ex}{Model}}
            & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 & Model 4\\
            \hhline{=::=::===}
            Class & Class 1 & \begin{itemize}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, topsep=0pt, itemsep =0pt, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}]
                \item Class 1 if $A=B$
                \item Class 2 otherwise
            \end{itemize} & Class 2 & Class 2\\
        \hhline{-||-||---}
            Method & Method 1 & Method 2 & Method 1 & Method 2\\
        \hhline{-||-||---}
            Time & Constant & Linear & Polylogarithmic & Exponential \\
        \hhline{-||-||---}
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}
    \begin{table}[htb]
        \centering
        \caption{Classifiaction}
        \label{table:cc}
        \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabular}{|c||*{1}{c|}|>\centering m{0.4\textwidth}|*{2}{c|}}\hline
                \backslashbox{Classification}{Model}
                & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 & Model 4\\\hline\hline
                Class & Class 1 & \begin{itemize}
                    \item Class 1 if $A=B$
                    \item Class 2 otherwise
                \end{itemize} & Class 2 & Class 2\\\hline
                Method & Method 1 & Method 2 & Method 1 & Method 2\\\hline
                Time & Constant & Linear & Polylogarithmic & Exponential \\\hline
            \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I increase the height of the third and fourth rows?

Comment: Also, can I center (in the middle) the contents of the cell containing the items?

Comment: with `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` for example the height of every row is doubled.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that seems to provide what you want:

[image]

There are three keys here to what I'm doing:

- I've save the list in a box and prior to making the table.  In the table I can then apply `\usebox` to the box to obtain the already formatted content.  By doing this, I can make the third column centers (as it appears you want).  Using the `minipage` removes the unwanted white space from before and after the `itemize` list (provided there's no content outside of the list.
- By using `\raisebox`, I'm basically able to give the appearance of adding a buffer of white space above and below the *list*.  This is a bit of a misnomer since what I've really done is just told LaTeX that the box's height and depth are a bit larger than they really are.  The syntax for `\raisebox` is

```
\raisebox{<lift>}
        [<optional height specification>]
        [<optional depth specification>]
        {<content>}
```

- I use *struts* to create some control over the spacing.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,graphicx}

\newcommand\aestrut[2]{\rule[#1]{0pt}{1pt}%%
                       \rule[#2]{0pt}{1pt}}
\newcommand\fixedstrut{\aestrut{2.5ex}{-1.5ex}}

\begin{document}
\newsavebox\aebox
\begin{lrbox}\aebox
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth-6pt}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Class 1 if $A=B$
      \item Class 2 otherwise
    \end{itemize} 
  \end{minipage}%%
\end{lrbox}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \caption{Classifiaction\aestrut{0pt}{-2ex}}
  \label{table:cc}
  \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c||*{1}{c|}|c|*{2}{c|}}\hline
      \backslashbox{\fixedstrut Classification}
                   {\fixedstrut Model} & 
      Model 1                          & 
      Model 2                          & 
      Model 3                          & 
      Model 4  
      \\\hline\hline
      Class                            & 
      Class 1                          & 
      \raisebox{0pt}[\height+2ex][\depth+2.5ex]{\usebox{\aebox}}
                                       & 
      Class 2                          & 
      Class 2  
      \\\hline
      \aestrut{3ex}{-2ex}%%
      Method                           & 
      Method 1                         & 
      Method 2                         & 
      Method 1                         & 
      Method 2
      \\\hline
      \aestrut{3ex}{-2ex}%%
      Time                             & 
      Constant                         & 
      Linear                           & 
      Polylogarithmic                  & 
      Exponential 
      \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
  }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```