# How to use \tabitem and (something like) \linebreak within the longtable environment?

Tags: tables, longtable

`\tabitem` is defined as

```
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
```

as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150650/149141).

This code

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|r|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Caption} & \textbf{One} & \textbf{Two} & \textbf{Three} \\ \hline\hline
        \textbf{First section} & & & \\ \hline\hline
        \tabitem Row 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
        \tabitem Row 2 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline\hline
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{Second section with a very long}\\\textbf{title that needs a line break}\end{tabular} & & & \\ \hline\hline
        \tabitem Row 3 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
        \tabitem Row 4 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Example table}
\end{table}
```

produces a table that looks like this:

[image]

But I don’t know how to achieve a result like this within the `longtable` environment. I suppose that the code has to be structured differently because, for example, `tabular` does not seem to work within this environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about clipped page numbers.  I just wanted to reduce the `paperheight` so that you could see that it was behaving like a `longtable`.

Provided `\ltabitem` only as an alternate definition for `\tabitem`.  Either should work in any situation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\newcommand\ltabitem{\makebox[1.3em][l]{\,$\bullet$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|l|r|r|r|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Caption} & \textbf{One} & \textbf{Two} & \textbf{Three} \\ \hline\hline
        \textbf{First section} & & & \\ \hline\hline
        \ltabitem Row 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
        \tabitem Row 2 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline\hline
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{Second section with a very long}\\\textbf{title that needs a line break}\end{tabular} & & & \\ \hline\hline
        \tabitem Row 3 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
        \tabitem Row 4 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ \hline
    \caption{Example table}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]