# How to remove additional spaces in table in latex

Tags: tables

I am using the following code to generate a table.

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{Some text}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{8.3cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Some text} & \textbf{Some text} & \textbf{Some text} \\
\hline

\textbf{Some text:}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some text
\item Some text
\item Some text
\end{itemize}
& 
43\%{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
-{$\newline$}
-{$\newline$}
& 
57\%{$\newline$}
-{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
\\
\hline
\textbf{Some text}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some text
\item Some text
\item Some text
\item Some text
\end{itemize}
&
25\%{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
-{$\newline$}
-{$\newline$}
-{$\newline$}
&
75\%{$\newline$}
-{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
\\
\hline
\textbf{Some text:}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some text
\item Some text
\end{itemize}
&
0\%{$\newline$}
-{$\newline$}
-{$\newline$}
&
100\%{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However, as shown in the figure below there are empty spaces (highlighted in yellow). I am just wondering if there is a way to remove those extra lines from the table?
[image]

I am happy to provide any other details if needed :)

Comment: Can you please provide us with a compilable document? When I compile your table with preamble `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}` I do not get such large spaces,

Comment: @marmot I am using the following document class `\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}`

Comment: Please add this (as well as `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) to your above code such that people have a complete example to play with.

Comment: @marmot Sure, I will add those details. By the way I am getting the same output in the following documentclasses as well; `\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}` and `\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}`

Comment: OK, thanks! I have another question (not that I could immediately answer it). Do you want the check marks and - be vertically aligned, i.e. at the same height, as the bullets of `itemize`? You might want to use e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150492/121799) instead of itemize, this would also solve the vertical space problem.

Comment: What is it that you think `{$\newline$}` does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` after each itemize and remove the last `{$\newline$}` of each column.

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{Some text}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{8.3cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Some text} & \textbf{Some text} & \textbf{Some text} \\
\hline

\textbf{Some text:}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some text
\item Some text
\item Some text
\end{itemize}
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
& 
43\%{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
-{$\newline$}
-
& 
57\%{$\newline$}
-{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
\checkmark
\\
\hline
\textbf{Some text}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some text
\item Some text
\item Some text
\item Some text
\end{itemize}
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
&
25\%{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
-{$\newline$}
-{$\newline$}
-
&
75\%{$\newline$}
-{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
\checkmark
\\
\hline
\textbf{Some text:}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some text
\item Some text
\end{itemize}
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
&
0\%{$\newline$}
-{$\newline$}
-
&
100\%{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
\checkmark
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here is a proposal how to format this table in a bit more appealing manner.

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!t]
  \caption{Some text}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Some text}  & \textbf{Some text} & \textbf{Some text} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Some text:} & 43\%               & 57\%               \\
    Some text           & \checkmark         & ---                \\
    Some text           & ---                & \checkmark         \\
    Some text           & ---                & \checkmark         \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{Some text}  & 25\%               & 75\%               \\
    Some text           & \checkmark         & ---                \\
    Some text           & ---                & \checkmark         \\
    Some text           & ---                & \checkmark         \\
    Some text           & ---                & \checkmark         \\
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{Some text:} & 0\%                & 100\%              \\
    Some text           & ---                & \checkmark         \\
    Some text           & ---                & \checkmark         \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \label{table1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that I had to put `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` **after the last `\item`** in each `itemize` for this to work.

Answer (score 5):

Two suggestions:

- Encase each `itemize` environment in a top-aligned `minipage` environment
- omit the final `{$\newline$}` directive in each group

Optional: remove the instruction `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}` and add `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\setlist[itemize]{nosep}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!t]
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\caption{Some text}
\label{table1}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{8.3cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{1.7cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Some text} & \textbf{Some text} & \textbf{Some text} 
\\ \hline

%% 1st group
\textbf{Some text:} & 43\% & 57\% \\ 
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some text
\item Some text
\item Some text
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
& 
\checkmark{$\newline$}
--{$\newline$}
--%{$\newline$}
& 
--{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
\checkmark%{$\newline$}
\\ \hline

%% 2nd group
\textbf{Some text} & 25\% & 75\%\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some text
\item Some text
\item Some text
\item Some text
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
&
\checkmark{$\newline$}
--{$\newline$}
--{$\newline$}
--%{$\newline$}
&
--{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
\checkmark{$\newline$}
\checkmark%{$\newline$}
\\ \hline

%% 3rd group
\textbf{Some text:} & 0\% & 100\% \\
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some text
\item Some text
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
&
--{$\newline$}
--%{$\newline$}
&
\checkmark{$\newline$}
\checkmark%{$\newline$}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice answer. I really like it. Thank you. :)