# \itemize in \tabular environment

Tags: itemize

While compiling my document i have several problems with itemizes in tabular environments, so I tried it with a simple test build and it didn't really work out.

This is the scipt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l l}
Test & 
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\end{itemize}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And the error says for line 8 and 9:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

I'm trying to find a simple solution for my problem that I can adapt into my other documents. That's why I'm using an example.

The error is the same as in my project so I think it has the same reason.

Thanks for help

Comment: Try with a p type column or with tabularx and an X type column.

Comment: Have you seen this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150492/120578 ?