# Making tabitem with linebreak and justified

Tags: tables, cv

I want to custom a bit [this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/forty-seconds-cv/pztcktmyngsk) great CV template found on Overleaf, but I've never used LaTeX before, and I'm quite struggling right now.

I wanted to recreate the basic function "cvitem" used in the template to insert record, but with a bullet list, and without the big indent. Here's what I did, based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150492/how-to-use-itemize-in-table-environment) beautiful solution found on StackExchange :

```
\newcommand{\cviteml}[7]{%
\parbox[t]{0.175\textwidth}{\raggedright #1} %
\parbox[t]{0.475\textwidth}{\raggedright \textbf{#2}} %
\parbox[t]{0.35\textwidth}{\raggedleft \footnotesize #3, \textit{#4}}\\
\midrule

    \hspace{0.02 cm} \tabitem #5 \\
    \hspace{0.02 cm} \tabitem #6 \\
    \hspace{0.02 cm} \tabitem #7 \\
```

}

Which produces this : 
[image]

It's almost perfect for me, except that I would like to be able to make it justified with linebreaks, like the following : [image]

I'm hope it's not a too dumb question, I've tried many thing right but nothing worked so far ^^' Thanks in advance !

Comment: Wouldn't a regular `itemize` environment be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've just found that addind those \tabitem in a \parbox will do the job perfectly !

edit : Sorry, I'm not really used with StackEchange too. Here's the my solution with the result :

```
\newcommand{\cviteml}[7]{%
\parbox[t]{0.175\textwidth}{\raggedright #1} %
\parbox[t]{0.475\textwidth}{\raggedright \textbf{#2}} %
\parbox[t]{0.35\textwidth}{\raggedleft \footnotesize #3, \textit{#4}}\\
\midrule

\tabitem \parbox[t]{0.975\textwidth}{#5} \\
\tabitem \parbox[t]{0.975\textwidth}{#6} \\
\tabitem \parbox[t]{0.975\textwidth}{#7} \\}
}
```

[image]