# Recreating the poker game diagram from "Non-Cooperative Games"

Tags: diagrams

To get used to working with LaTeX, I've started recreating famous papers using their respective journal's classes. In John Nash's [Non-Cooperative Games](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969529), the turns of a simple poker game are laid out in the following way:

[image: poker game diagram]

I've tried sticking `enumerate`s in a `tabular` but the result never looks right. So, how can I properly recreate this diagram in LaTeX, preferably without depending on something like Tikz?

**EDIT**: I now have a minimal working example. All that's left is to remove the stray vertical line.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\rom}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral #1\relax}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|l|l|}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\small First Moves} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\small Second Moves} \\
\cline{2-3}
\multirow{3}{*}{\rom{1}}
& $\alpha$ Open on \textit{high} & $\kappa$ Call \rom{3} on \textit{low} \\
& $\beta$  Open on \textit{low}  & $\lambda$ Call \rom{2} on \textit{low} \\
&                                & $\mu$ Call \rom{2} and \rom{3} on \textit{low} \\
\cline{2-3}
\multirow{3}{*}{\rom{2}}
& $\gamma$ Call \rom{1} on \textit{low} & $\nu$ Call \rom{3} on \textit{low} \\
& $\delta$ Open on \textit{high}        & $\xi$ Call \rom{3} and \rom{1} on \textit{low} \\
& $\epsilon$ Open on \textit{low}       & \\
\cline{2-3}
\multirow{4}{*}{\rom{3}}
& $\zeta$ Call \rom{1} and \rom{2} on \textit{low} & \hphantom{$\mu$ }Player \rom{3} never gets a second move \\
& $\eta$ Open on \textit{low} & \\
& $\theta$ Call \rom{1} on \textit{low} & \\
& $\iota$ Call \rom{2} on \textit{low} & \\
\cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: my copy]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You should edit your question to include a minimum working example of code.  But without that, you could perhaps make use of `aligned` (amsmath) environments or else TABstacks (tabstackengine).

Comment: do the answers to this question help?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150492/15036

Comment: @Thruston mostly, I now have a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to ditch the vertical rules and use `booktabs` to add some padding. The final code incorporates answers from [here](/a/23491/225647) and [here](/a/150650/225647):

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\rom}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral #1\relax}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c l l}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\footnotesize First Moves} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\footnotesize Second Moves} \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
\multirow{3}{*}{\rom{1}}
& $\alpha$ Open on \textit{high} & $\kappa$ Call \rom{3} on \textit{low} \\
& $\beta$  Open on \textit{low}  & $\lambda$ Call \rom{2} on \textit{low} \\
&                                & $\mu$ Call \rom{2} and \rom{3} on \textit{low} \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
\multirow{3}{*}{\rom{2}}
& $\gamma$ Call \rom{1} on \textit{low} & $\nu$ Call \rom{3} on \textit{low} \\
& $\delta$ Open on \textit{high}        & $\xi$ Call \rom{3} and \rom{1} on \textit{low} \\
& $\epsilon$ Open on \textit{low} \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
\multirow{4}{*}{\rom{3}}
& $\zeta$ Call \rom{1} and \rom{2} on \textit{low} & \hphantom{$\mu$ }Player \rom{3} never gets a second move \\
& $\eta$ Open on \textit{low} \\
& $\theta$ Call \rom{1} on \textit{low} \\
& $\iota$ Call \rom{2} on \textit{low} \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: table with booktabs]